# VS2013 text operation - swap stuff from left and right of operator

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2013

In my project i have lot of functionality like this:
x = this.x;
y = this.y;
z = this.z;
etc.

In another function i might need the following:
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.z = z;

In the old version of visual studio i could make a macro to get this done for easier creation of these pieces of code (i mean i have a lot of these constructions with list populating about 10-50 fields) and in the current version i can still do the same with regex replaces in the text finder, however i am wondering if there is an option for this in VS2013 itself or a way to automate it.

Comment: Try [Visual Commander](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d) to run your macro?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing things a bit more manually, you could use the [Column select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/729s2dhh%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in visual studio. If your equal-signs are aligned (as they are in your example), you can ALT-select all the variables as a rectangular selection, and cut/paste them from left to right and vice-versa.

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3SnTtbZKhY8) you can see the column select in action, just hold the ALT-key while selecting.

Comment: I already use the column select for a lot of stuff i need to reorganise and would use this if the fields would not all have different size names. If not i would take this as a solution any day.